# Setting Legend on multiple columns with Bokeh Charts

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to set the number of columns in the legend using bokeh. Using matplotlib there is a simple keyword ncol but I cannot find a way to do it in bokeh.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: without code! please add your code(abstract case) here, for the future readers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of Bokeh `0.12.3` Bokeh legends only support complete orientations `'horizontal'` or `'vertical'`:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#orientation

So you could have a legend arranged horizontally in one row and several columns, by doing

```
plot.legend.orientation = "horizontal"
```

But there is not any way to have e.g. a legend with two rows by two columns. There is an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3880) to add this capability as a feature.